# Why does "||".split("\\|").length return 0 and not 3?

Tags: java, regex, split, apex-code

When there are adjacent separators in the split expression I expect null or an empty string--not have it eliminated.

The Java code is below:

```
public class splitter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int size = "||".split("\\|").length;
        assert size == 3 : "size should be 3 and not " + size;
    }
}
```

I expected to get either { "", "", "" } or { null, null, null }.  Either would be fine.

Perhaps there's a regular expression that will not be fooled by empty words?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument `split` method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

The javadoc for [`split(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) elaborates:

> The `limit` parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit *n* is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most *n* - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than *n*, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If *n* is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. **If *n* is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.**

(emphasis mine)

So to return an array of empty strings, call `"||".split("\\|", -1)`

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  I like your answer much better.

Comment: ".. much better than mine." I meant to write.

Answer (score 0):

I need to take a closer look at Paul's answer (his looks simpler), but I was able to find something about look-ahead expressions that solve the assertions (I apologize that the code is in Apex--it just wraps Java).

```
static testMethod void testPatternStringSplit() {
        Pattern aPattern = Pattern.Compile('(?=\\|)');
        system.assertEquals(3, aPattern.split('||').size());
        system.assertEquals(3, aPattern.split(' | | ').size());
        system.assertEquals(3, aPattern.split('a|b|c').size());
        system.assertEquals(3, aPattern.split('a|b|').size());
        system.assertEquals(3, aPattern.split('|b|c').size());
        system.assertEquals(3, aPattern.split('|b|').size());
}
```

I need to write some code to test Paul's ...

Comment: That won't give him three empty strings when splitting "||" though - it will give him one empty string and two "|"s.